# $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism at $p$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are regular surfaces and $\phi: U \subset S_1 \to S_2$
is a differentiable mapping of an open set $U \subset S_1$ such that the differential $d\phi_p$ of $\phi$ at $p \in U$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism at $p$.

I think we have to apply Inverse Function Theorem.

Require Hints to proceed with the problem.

Comment: Compose take charts $h_1$, $h_2$ and compose: $h_2\circ\phi\circ h_1^{-1}$.